# Private http: HttpClient in or out of constructor?

Tags: angular, http, routes

If I use:

```
private http: HttpClient
constructor () {
}
```

I get ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'post' of undefined

If I use:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}
```

I get Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for DataService: (?).

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, concat } from "rxjs";

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

export class DataService {
  

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  private token: string = "";
  private tokenExpiration: Date;
  public store: string = "";
  public user: string = "";

  public login(creds) {
    this.store = creds.strNum;
    this.user = creds.empID;
    return this.http.post("/Account/CreateToken", creds)
      .pipe(map(response => {
        let tokenInfo = response;
        this.token = tokenInfo["token"];
        this.tokenExpiration = tokenInfo["expiration"];

        return true;
      }));
  }

}
```

Not sure where to turn.

Comment: have you included httpclientModule in the rootmodule ?

Comment: You need to include the "Injectable" decorator above the class definition. You have the TypeScript import, but you are not applying to Angular. Without it, you can't "inject" other services into your service.

Comment: what a catch @DavidFontes !

Comment: DOH! Thanks @DavidFontes. How do I mark your answer as correct?

Comment: @micronyks Thanks :P Will T I have added an answer with the solution and the code sample :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the "Injectable" decorator above the class definition. You have the TypeScript import, but you are not applying to Angular. Without it, you can't "inject" other services into your service.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
// ...

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include **Injectable** Decorator in your service.ts file. Make sure that you have included **HttpClientModule** in you App Module file.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, concat } from "rxjs";

import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataService {


  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

  }

  private token: string = "";
  private tokenExpiration: Date;
  public store: string = "";
  public user: string = "";

  public login(creds) {
    this.store = creds.strNum;
    this.user = creds.empID;
    return this.http.post("/Account/CreateToken", creds)
      .pipe(map(response => {
        let tokenInfo = response;
        this.token = tokenInfo["token"];
        this.tokenExpiration = tokenInfo["expiration"];

        return true;
      }));
  }

}
```